# Issues with Jquery Placeholder Plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, placeholder

I've tried using two different jquery plugins to get placeholders to work in ie9, [Andrew Jones one](http://andrew-jones.com/jquery-placeholder-plugin/) and [Mathias Bynens one](https://github.com/mathiasbynens).

Unfortunately, both of them are giving me the same set of issues, that for the life of me I cannot figure out. The first issue is, every now and then in the JS console I get the following error :

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'placeholder'
```

...which is as if the script didn't load, even though it has. Its usually the 50/50 chance of that error showing up when I refresh the page. The next issue I'm encountering is that sometimes the placeholders won't even show up, but then when I click the input field and then click somewhere else the placeholder text will finally appear.

This is being used in a rails app. I'm using placeholder like so, at the top of `main.js document.ready()`

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s(?!10.0)/)) {

    $(":input[placeholder]").placeholder();
}
```

And I am including the script in `layouts/application.html.erb` like so:

```
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "normalize"%>
    <%=stylesheet_link_tag "main"%>
    <%=stylesheet_link_tag "r"%>
    <%=stylesheet_link_tag "1140"%>
    <%=stylesheet_link_tag "ie"%>
    <%=stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.placeholder.min"%>
    <%=javascript_include_tag "vendor/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"%>
    <%=javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js"%>
    <%=javascript_include_tag "vendor/css3-mediaqueries.js"%>
    <%=javascript_include_tag "vendor/jquery.fitvids.js"%>

    <%=javascript_include_tag "plugins.js"%>
    <%=javascript_include_tag "rails.js"%>
    <%=javascript_include_tag "jquery.placeholder.min.js"%>
    <%=javascript_include_tag "main.js.erb"%>   

    <%=csrf_meta_tag %>
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, do you progressed in through the fix of this bug ? I'm experiencing the same problem with a node.js application (so I can affirm that the bug isn't caused by the Rail stuff if it can help !)

Comment: The little difference with your situation is that when I reload the page, the plugin is reload correctly. I have to empty my navigator cache and reboot it to get the bug again.

Comment: It turned out that I was including jquery twice. The extra jquery include was all the way at the bottom of my layout file (lefover from our designer's static html), so it had eluded me for awhile.